# Validate a Facebook Token

Tags: angular, facebook, oauth-2.0

New to FB, please forgive the stupid question.

My web application uses FB and Google authentication. Authentication is all I need, nothing else. Using `angularx-social-login`, I'm able to log in using a FB credential, get response via redirect URL as:

```
authToken: 'ABC...'
email: ...
firstName: ...
...
```

Great, now I supposed to submit this `authToken` to my own API server to establish a session. So how does my API know this token is genuine? I found [FB's manually build a login flow, Confirming Identity](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/manually-build-a-login-flow#confirm), there is also `code`, `response_type` and `access_token`. I'm lost. How to obtain them?

Just an example, my app also uses Google authentication, there is an endpoint accepts only the `authToken` or a client library like

```
const {OAuth2Client} = require('google-auth-library');
const googlelib = new OAuth2Client(googleClientID); 
await googlelib.verifyIdToken(
    {idToken: toBeChecked_ShouldBeAuthToken, audience: myGoogleClientID}, 
    (bad, good) => ...
```

Comment: https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/access-tokens/debugging-and-error-handling exists.

Answer (score 0):

This is a well known problem when trying to use foreign access tokens. My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2020/05/23/federation-logins/) explains the preferred OAuth option, where an Authorization Server manages most of the complexity for your apps.

Consider use of an open source or cloud system such as Keycloak that does this for free or at low cost. There are 2 big areas to OAuth:

- Protecting your data
- Multiple login methods

On the first point, even if you work out how to validate Facebook tokens in APIs, they will not contain the claims your APIs need to authorize by.